# JBoss cluster - session replication on demand / disabled?

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, java-ee-6, wildfly, infinispan

I have an application that I am 'clusterising' to run across multiple JBoss AS 7.2.0 nodes in standalone-full-ha mode with mod_cluster in front (using sticky sessions)

The cluster works...kind of, I am constantly running into issues with ConcurrentModificationException's and Serialization errors from Infinispan as it is constantly replicating state between nodes, the application does a lot of long-running processing work so there is a lot of arrays stored in memory at any given time which I assume is one of the causes

I have spent a fair amount of time trying to work around these but I think I am fighting a losing battle

Since I do not really need 'High Availability', is it possible to configure JBoss (or Infinispan subsystem) to only replicate my Session/EJB's on demand?

Eg. The only time I really need it is when I am taking a node down and I want to move its state to another node, so I would like to be able to trigger it from within my application

...and if this is not possible, how can I disable Session/Ejb replication entirely?

Comment: If you really want to have control over what you replicate, you should create your own Infinispan caches and manage them yourself. Otherwise, what the application server is doing is making sure that if a node crashes, data will survive in another node, so it'd not make sense for you to halt that really. What you can do is mark fields that you want serializing as `transient`, and `ConcurrentModificationException`s are probably due to wrong choice of collection, e.g. a non-concurrent collection being accessed concurrently.

Comment: @GalderZamarreño thanks, creating my own cache sounds like a lot of work, could you provide details on how to disable replication then? Also regarding your last point, does that mean I should only be using Concurrent collections with Infinispan?

Comment: Marking things transient should avoid getting them replicated. In terms of collections, I don't have context to know what, how and which collections are being used concurrently by who. All I can see is that you're making some assumptions about your collections that are wrong. You're using non-concurrent collections but they're accessed concurrently.